# Android: How to get list of countries and cities

Tags: countries

I want to build a database of all countries (with longitude and latitude) and their cities. The database will be used in my android application. Any idea where I can find this information to build the database ?

Answer (score -2):

Here is a link that I found that shows a list of all countries, capitals, longitude and latitude.http://www.csgnetwork.com/llinfotable.html